# Change Value In Session Array

Tags: php, session

This will change a variable in the session

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('name', "value");
```

But could you in the same way (directly) change any specific value of a session array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean to change the value of a key of a JSession property that is an array.

You have set your session property somewhere earlier

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$mySessionVar = array('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b');
$session->set('mySessionVar', $mySessionVar);
```

Now you want to change that:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
// You get that property
$mySessionVar = $session->get('mySessionVar');

// It's an array. So you change the value for the array key
$mySessionVar['b'] = 'c';

// You set/update the same session variable
$session->set('mySessionVar', $mySessionVar);

// Now it holds the new data
$myNewSessionVar = $session->get('mySessionVar');

//echo '<pre>' . print_r($myNewSessionVar, true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Session data is stored as Registry. Use keys separated by a dot to access nested properties.

```
$session->set('array.key', 'value');
```